# How to replace text on field after click Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have HTML code with inline element:

```
<span class="title" ng-click="update()">Rock</span>
```

How to replace this element on input element after click for edit?

And then after push enter on input return back span element?

I tried with directives `ng-hide(), ng-show()`. But I wonder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either

```
<span class="title" ng-hide="isEdited" ng-click="update()">Rock</span>
```

or

```
<span class="title" ng-show="!isEdited" ng-click="update()">Rock</span>
```

or even

```
<span class="title" ng-if="!isEdited" ng-click="update()">Rock</span>
```

In any case you will want to reference something that can be truthy. For example in your controller you would have something like this in your function

```
/*the init function just makes sure that everything is setup 
and nothing caries over from any local storage or anything 
else you may be using*/

init();
init function(){
  $scope.isEdited = false;
}

$scope.update = function(){
  $scope.isEdited = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set a variable that contains the state;

```
<html>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainController as $ctrl">
      <span ng-if="!$ctrl.isInEditMode" class="title" ng-click="$ctrl.update()" ng-bind="$ctrl.spanText"></span>
      <div ng-if="$ctrl.isInEditMode">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Value for rock" ng-model="$ctrl.spanText" />  
        <button ng-click="$ctrl.update()">Done</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    this.isInEditMode = false;
    this.spanText = 'Rock';
    this.update = (function() {
      this.isInEditMode = !this.isInEditMode;
    }).bind(this);
});
```

I have prepared a Codepen that shows an possible solution: http://codepen.io/stefferd/pen/QdQrrv